# Usar env entries desde un EJB

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb

Estoy usando la librería Twitter4J para usar la API de Twitter.
Esta librería la estoy usando en un EJB sin estado de esta manera:

```
@Stateless
    public class TwitterSearchBean implements TwitterSearchBeanLocal {


        @Resource(name = "TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY")
        private String oauthConsumerKey;
        @Resource(name = "TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET")
        private String oauthConsumerSecret;
        @Resource(name = "TWITTER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN")
        private String oauthAccessToken;
        @Resource(name = "TWITTER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")
        private String oauthAccessTokenSecret;
        private Twitter twitter;
        private final TweetDataMapper mapper = new TweetDataMapper();

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(oauthConsumerKey)
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(oauthConsumerSecret)
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(oauthAccessToken)
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(oauthAccessTokenSecret);
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            twitter = tf.getInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Tweet> search(final String keyword) {
            Query query = new Query(keyword + " -filter:retweets -filter:links -filter:replies -filter:images");
            query.setCount(20);
            query.setLocale("en");
            query.setLang("en");
            try {
                QueryResult queryResult = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweetsStatus = queryResult.getTweets();
                Collection<Tweet> tweets = mapper.transform(tweetsStatus);
                return (List<Tweet>) tweets;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Las claves necesarias para el ConfigurationBuilder están declaradas dentro del archivosun-ejb-jar.xml on src/main/resources/META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 EJB 3.1//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_1-0.dtd">
    <sun-ejb-jar>
        <enterprise-beans>
            <session>
                <ejb-name>TwitterSearchBean</ejb-name>
                <env-entry>
                    <env-entry-name>TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY</env-entry-name>
                    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                    <env-entry-value>please enter key here</env-entry-value>
                </env-entry>
                <env-entry>
                    <env-entry-name>TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET</env-entry-name>
                    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                    <env-entry-value>please enter key here</env-entry-value>
                </env-entry>
                <env-entry>
                    <env-entry-name>TWITTER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN</env-entry-name>
                    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                    <env-entry-value>please enter key here</env-entry-value>
                </env-entry>
                <env-entry>
                    <env-entry-name>TWITTER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET</env-entry-name>
                    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                    <env-entry-value>please enter key here</env-entry-value>
                </env-entry>
            </session>
        </enterprise-beans>
    </sun-ejb-jar>
```

Estos recurso no son inyectados y las claves son nulas. ¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el problema o conoce una alternativa?

Comment: ¿Qué servidor estás usando? Porque las referencias que encuentro a `sun-ejb-jar.xml` no coinciden con tu estructura de XML; se parece más bien a la de `ejb-jar.xml` a secas

Comment: estoy usando Glassfish 4.1. ¿entonces tendría que usar ejb-jar en vez de sun-ejb-jar?

Comment: Bueno, para empezar parece que en Glassfish 4 y siguientes ya no usan `sun-ejb-jar.xml` sino `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` (http://javahowto.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/glassfish-ejb-jarxml-and-sun-ejb-jarxml.html), y la estructura de esos ficheros no coincides con la que tu expones en tu pregunta... Te diría que repases la documentación.

Comment: ok, yo he seguido el ejemplo de aquí http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/how-to-implement-ejb-30-in-ejb-jarxml.html para implementarlo. Revisaré la documentación.

Comment: Al mirar artículos técnicos conviene mirar la fecha del artículo... Un artículo de hace 8 años puede dar una primera idea de como afrontar el problema, pero es muy improbable que lo puedas aplicar literalmente a la última versión del software.